# hierarchical retreival of records in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, hierarchy, recursive

I am using postgresql-9.2 . I have a table of products which stores the information about the products and its child table is content table , which contains the products linked to it.

PRODUCT MASTER TABLE

```
MASTER_ID                NAME 

1                      PRODUCT1
2                      PRODUCT2
3                      PRODUCT3
4                      PRODUCT4
5                      PRODUCT5
6                      PRODUCT6
7                      PRODUCT7
8                      PRODUCT8
9                      PRODUCT9
10                     PRODUCT10
```

PRODUCT_CONTENT TABLE

```
PRODUCT_CONTENT_ID                     PRODUCT_MASTER_ID        CONTENT_ID
A1                                          1                       2
A2                                          1                       3
A3                                          1                       4
A4                                          2                       3
A5                                          2                       4
A6                                          2                       5
A7                                          3                       5
A8                                          3                       7
A9                                          3                       8
A10                                         5                       8
A11                                         7                       9
A12                                         8                       10
```

I am writing a query to retrieve all the products(ids associated with them) with their content products which should display something like this hierarchy

```
MAINPRODUCT                     SUBPRODUCT
    2                               3
    2                               4
    2                               5
    3                               5
    3                               7
    3                               8
    5                               8   
    7                               9
    8                               10
```

I have written the following query

```
 SELECT PM1.PRODUCT_MASTER_ID AS MAIN,PC.CONTENT_ID AS CONTENT
    FROM PRODUCT_CONTENT PC 
    LEFT JOIN PRODUCT_MASTER PM ON PM.PRODUCT_MASTER_ID = PC.CONTENT_ID
    LEFT JOIN PRODUCT_MASTER PM1 ON 
    PM1.PRODUCT_MASTER_ID = PC.PRODUCT_MASTER_ID
    WHERE PC.PRODUCT_MASTER_ID IN 
      (
       SELECT PC.CONTENT_ID FROM PRODUCT_CONTENT PC 
       LEFT JOIN PRODUCT_MASTER PM ON 
          PM.PRODUCT_MASTER_ID = PC.CONTENT_ID
       LEFT JOIN PRODUCT_MASTER PM1 ON 
          PM1.PRODUCT_MASTER_ID = PC.PRODUCT_MASTER_ID
       WHERE PC.PRODUCT_MASTER_ID IN ('1')
      )
```

IT RETURNS SOMETHING LIKE THIS

```
MAIN            CONTENT

2                       3
2                       4
2                       5
3                       5
3                       7
3                       8
```

Comment: Check out recursive queries: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

Comment: Actually I have to get all the rows in the Record later , to execute it one by one ,,, That's why I cant use Recursive queries...

Comment: Why not? I don't understand your argument.

Comment: Ok. I Have to write a query to get the rows in a Record loop and process it one by one . Is that possible with recursive queries?

Comment: Please (please, please, please) read the formatting guidance that's shown when you post and *use the preview*. While you're at it, it's nice if you provide the sample data (thanks for providing) as `create table` and `insert` statmeents.

Comment: @Geek First, you rarely actually have to process things in a loop. Usually you land up able to do it with insert/update/delete using joins, or using a CTE. Second, even if you do have to loop, it makes *more* sense to fetch the rows once then iterate over the result.

Comment: @Craig Ringer ,Ok I get it , I have to fetch rows once in for all using joins and then iterate it, So how can I change the query to get the desired result ?

Comment: Update with sample data or an http://sqlfiddle.com/ and I'll have a play tomorrow.

Comment: [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8c406/2)  link with sample data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16705/discussion-between-geek-and-craig-ringer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple adjacency list traversal problem. You're not even trying to build paths, just find nodes from a root node or set. That's pretty much a textbook example of what a recursive CTE is for.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8c406/12

```
WITH RECURSIVE children(product_content_id, product_master_id, content_id) AS (
  SELECT pc.product_content_id, pc.product_master_id, pc.content_id
  FROM product_content pc
  WHERE pc.product_master_id = '1'
  UNION
  SELECT pc.product_content_id, pc.product_master_id, pc.content_id
  FROM product_content pc
  INNER JOIN children c ON (pc.product_master_id = c.content_id)
)
SELECT
  product_master_id AS mainproduct,
  content_id AS subproduct
FROM children;
```

You could pretty much adapt this from the [PostgreSQL manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html), which includes an example on edgelist graph traversal.

---

Database design side-note: *Please don't use character fields for numbers. It's also not usually a good idea to use keys like `A10` if the `A` and `10` parts have any kind of separate meaning at all.*

Comment: Thanx for your time. I will remember the notes provided.One additional thing I have to ask you is that the resulting query contains  all the records. Now I have to get main product id  one by one to implement some business logic.How can I do that ? Plz help

Comment: @Geek That's not really clear enough to help you much. Just iterate over them client-side? Use a cursor? A temp table? Wrap the whole thing up as a subquery-in-FROM or another CTE term and then `SELECT my_business_logic_function(record) FROM the_results`?  Hard to really say without a useful description of what you need. If you find yourself stuck, post a new *detailed* question on that problem and then post a link to it here. Include sample data, expected results, description of business logic, whether business logic is client-side/server side, etc etc tec.